What is the Lisp's symbol equivalent of JavaScript?
So in Lisp/Scheme, there are these 'symbols', which are basically, if I understand correctly, and correct me if I'm wrong, references to variables (not their values). I was wondering if there's a JavaScript equivalent to that?
Thank you!

Please [edit] your question to actually show "these 'symbols'".

@Someprogrammerdude I would love to, but honestly I don't understand them fully myself, which is one of the reasons I'm trying to find a comparison since I'm much more familiar with JavaScript.

The simplest way would be to copy-paste (as text) a small snippet of code containing the pieces you're wondering about, and how it's used. Please take some time to refresh [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

The question is valid and self-contained, and there is nothing to show: a symbol is a type in "Lisp" (at least in Common Lisp, Racket ...), without equivalent in the majority of other programming languages. The question is akin to "What is the JavaScript equivalent of C structures". There is no specific C structure to show for the question to make sense.


[symbols] which are basically, if I understand correctly, and correct me if I'm wrong, references to variables (not their values)

Symbols in Common Lisp are a made of a name, a package, and a property list.
They are not necessarily "references to variables", but this is one of the possible uses of symbols. Symbols are efficient because they are interned when reading the source code, meaning that the same combination of name and package object refers to the same symbol.
Global variables and functions can be referenced by their identifiers, which are symbols. But symbols can also be used without being tied to variables or functions.

A lisp symbol is an object that is used to make code as data. In Javascript we  have a Symbol class:
const test = Symbol("name");
test.descripion; // => "name"

However while we in Lisp can create code like '(+ 1 2) and use eval to evaluate that structure, JavaScipt uses strings in their eval. Thus this symbol class cannot really be used in the same way as a lisp symbol. Actually JavaScript Symbol is more of a gensym to get a unique key in an object rather than to be used to create code.
The AST of lisp is the easiest, while all algol languages has much more difficult AST and it would me more difficult to create structures for it. I'm guessing if JS would to get lisp type macros we could imagine that a Symbol is a symbol and that if it got some kind of literal form eg. #name is the same as Symbol("name") and #{..} was some kind of literal for a snippet so that you could do #{const test = ${a} + this.calc(${b})} with a being #name and b being 100 would produce a structure with toString const test = name + this.calc(100) and I guess this is like quasiquote and could be done like list in lisp where in JS you use Node(#const, Node(#test), Node(#=), ...)` or something..
I guess you should look at algol languages that has advanced macros, like Nermle :-)
